# Gremlin Python(AWS Neptune) get vertices with relations to list of other vertices

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

New to Gremlin_python and GraphDBs in general, we are using AWS neptune. I am trying to get a list of scenarios that have relations to a set of different tags e.g. give me all scenarios that has tag A and tag B. But the set of tags can be dynamic(from 1 to 10 elements).

The question as i understand it in GraphDB therms is:

Give me all vertices that has an outgoing edge with the label=tag to vertices with label A AND B. [Picture of the Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EKzA.png)

For a none dynamic approach i get it to work with this guery:

```
e = g.V().and_(__.out('tag').hasLabel('A'), __.out('tag').hasLabel('B')).label().toList()
```

But i am not able to get this to work with a list of tags. I also did try this but it just generate an OR statement and i have not found a way to get it to do and:

```
label_list = ['A','B']
e = g.V().where(__.out('has tag').hasLabel((*label_list))).label().toList()
```

I also tried this approach with just getting the message "Connection was closed by server", i have seen this many times with AWS Neptune that instead of generating an error message a get connection closed instead anyone know way this happens?:

```
label_list = ['A','B']
e = g.V().and_(map(lambda x:__.out('has tag').hasLabel(x), label_list)).label().toList()
print(len(e))
```

We are testing this in the sage maker notebook using python 3.8.

So internet can you please generate an answer for me here?

BR
Jon

List of includes in the notebook:

```
import yaml
from pathlib import Path
import json
import os

#from __future__  import print_function  # Python 2/3 compatibility

from gremlin_python import statics
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import T
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Order
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Cardinality
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Column
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Direction
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Operator
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import P
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import TextP
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Pop
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Scope
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Barrier
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Bindings
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import WithOptions

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from loguru import logger
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did find one solution for the problem. More in a Python kind of way, than Gremlin. To flatten a list of code worked, but maybe there is a more readable solution.

```
label_list = ['A','B']
e = g.V().and_(*[__.out('tag').hasLabel(x) for x in label_list]).label().toList()
```

A net trick i did figure out here is that you can send a list of tuples to the code. So you can dynamically add ANDs for both the out() and hasLabel().

```
label_list = [('tag','A'),('tag','B'),('app','C')]
e = g.V().and_(*[__.out(x[0]).hasLabel(x[1]) for x in label_list]).label().toList()
```

Comment: The updated query in the other answer essentially does this. Were you able to try using the corrections discussed for `is` and `within` ?

Comment: if i do run:
    e = g.V().where(__.out('tag').hasLabel(P.within('A','B')).label().dedup().count().is_(3))
    e
The neptune notebook generates:
[['V'], ['where', [['out', 'tag'], ['hasLabel', within(['A', 'B'])], ['label'], ['dedup'], ['count'], ['is', 3]]], ['values', '_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_'], ['values', '_ipython_canary_method_should_not_exist_']]

I need to read up on what the functions you are using are doing to understand what the query tries to do. But what i would like and what my query delivers is a list of the vertices that have a edge tag to vertex A and B.

Comment: And again if i just use the were within statements as you suggests in this way

e = g.V().where(__.out('tag').hasLabel(P.within('A','B'))).label().dedup().toList()
len(e)

It still generates a OR statement and not a AND statement. E.G. the list includes a all vertices with a edge(with label tag) to the vertex with label A OR a edge(with label tag) to the vertex with label B.

Comment: Every call using Python needs to end in a "terminal" step such as `next()` , `iterate()`, `toList()` etc. This particular call should probably end with `toList()` as there can be multiple results and you likely want them all at once. It is the `count()` part that guarantees you have at least one of each.

Comment: Yes! That worked now as well. i was 100% that i tried it with a toList at the end.
I just need to read up on how count and the other reducing barrier steps works.

Comment: It's interesting that three `hasLabel` inside an `and` step performed so much better than the counting approach. I will investigate that further. I assume it has something to do with the `and` test being able to terminate as soon as it has found one of each rather than counting them all.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `within` predicate for this if the test comes down to "has any of these property values (tags)".

```java
g.V().out('tag').hasLabel(within('A','B','C'))
```

UPDATED: Based on comments.

If you need to ensure that from the starting vertex there is at least one edge to each of the desired label types, you can modify the query above as follows:

```java
g.V().where(out('tag').hasLabel(within('A','B','C')).
      label().dedup().count().is(3))
```

UPDATED 2023-02-22

In this particular case the `within` is not really needed, although  the query optimizer should generate the same query plan regardless, The query could be written as:

```java
g.V().where(out('tag').hasLabel('A','B','C').
      label().dedup().count().is(3))
```

Comment: Sorry maybe i was unclear, i did update the post. it should be "has all" and not "has any". 
As in a logical AND between the statements and not a OR. 

BR
Jon

Comment: So just to clarify, the nodes have multiple labels like `A::B::C` , or there must be an edge to all of the label types from a given start?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example that handles the latter case.

Comment: I did add a picture with the setup that i have. there are more then the 2 node of scenario1 and scenario2 in the database. 

I dont get the is and within commands to work with gremlin-python and aws-neptune. Are they only Groovy-console commands? 

If i remove the within and is. this command still generates an OR combination.

Comment: They are standard Gremlin - BUT - sometimes Gremlin step names conflict with Python reserved words . In such cases you will need to suffix them with an underscore. So `is()` when using Python becomes `is_()`. For `within` , try `P.within()` - if neither work you may need to import additional items.